# Making sense of where "const" goes in a declaration

Tags: c++, c, syntax, constants

I am having trouble finding an intuitive pattern for the way const is used in declarations in the C and C++ languages.  Here are some examples:

```
const int a;    //Const integer
int const a;    //Const integer
const int * a;  //Pointer to constant integer
int * const a;  //Const pointer to an integer
int const * a const;    //Const pointer to a const integer
```

In lines 1 and 2, it seems `const` can come before or after `int`, which is what it modifies.

1. So how, in line 4, does the compiler decide that `const` is modifying `*` (pointer) rather than `int`?
2. What is the rule that the compiler follows for deciding which thing the `const` applies to?
3. Does it follow the same rule for `*`?

Comment: obligatory link to the [clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: If there are no arrays or functions involved, simply **reading from right to left** may help, too: `int const * const a`: "`a` is a const pointer to a const int".

Comment: Mark, if you had submitted that as an answer, I would have checked it.  Very useful and really helps me figure it out!

Comment: @Adam the answers below provide terrific explanations, and I didn't feel just the link provided a *real* answer; glad it helped, though.

Comment: I never understood why the "clockwise spiral" rule was a *clockwise* spiral. You're reading a one-dimensional string of tokens, so you could just as easily draw your imaginary spiral counter-clockwise by going "down" instead of "up"...

Comment: @Mark Elliot: Beware that the spiral rule has some *strange* cases... `const int x[10][20]` does not say that *`x is an array of 10 int array of [20] const`*. But rather *`x` is an array of 10 arrays of 20 const integers*

Comment: Isn't this question asked like a 1000 times already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler generally reads the type from right-to-left, so:

```
T const& const
```

Would be read as:

```
 const (a constant)
 & (to a reference)
 const (to a constant)
 T (of type T)
```

So, basically the keyword "const" modifies everything that precedes it. However, there is an exception in the case where "const" comes first, in which case  it modifies the item directly to the right of it:

```
const T& const
```

The above is read as:

```
const (a constant)
& (to a reference)
const T (to a constant of type T)
```

And the above is equivalent to T const& const.

While this is how the compiler does it, I really just recommend memorizing the cases "T", "const T", "const T&", "const T*", "const T& const", "const T* const", "T& const", and "T* const". You will rarely encounter any other variation of "const", and when you do, it's probably a good idea to use a typedef.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how the compiler does it, not just how "a human can do it", which is really what I was asking for.

Comment: I believe there is no such thing as a "constant reference" (or, in other words, they are always constant). So `T & const` is not correct semantically. VC++2010 gives a warning and ignores the `const`. Just a reminder. :)

Comment: -1 for the bad example. You should have used a pointer here, not a reference.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you always place `const` to the *right* of the type, you can read a variable declaration as a sentence from right to left:

```
int const x;        // x is a constant int
int *const x;       // x is a constant pointer to an int
int const *x;       // x is a pointer to a constant int
int const *const x; // x is a constant pointer to a constant int
```

This still works if you put `const` to the left of a type, but requires a bit more mental effort. Note that this works just as well with pointers-to-pointers (and higher order constructs):

```
int *const *const x; // x is a constant pointer to a constant pointer to an int
```

Comment: So the basic rule is read right to left, and if the left-most thing is a `const`, then it applies to the thing directly to its right. So `const` applies to the thing on the left, unless it has nothing on the left, so it applies to the thing on the right.

Answer (score 2):

For pointers, here's one I picked up from one of Scott Meyers's books (I think). Draw a vertical line through the *, and then whatever's on the same side of the line as the const keyword is the thing that's const.

To clarify:

`int * const a` means that a is const, not the int. And "a" is a pointer to the (non-const) int.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start off, this question is more of a personal preference. For the leisure programmer, it's more of a personal style. However, for those that deal with corporates, there can be some kind of coding convention that they layout for programmers to follow such that everyone comes out with consistent coding styles.

(1) For const `int * const a;` it means that you can't change what your pointer points to but you can modify that memory location.

(2) The 'const' is decided by you, as the programmer, whether you want the address the pointer  points to, to be constant or if you want the pointer to NOT modify the pointer it points to.

(3) Yes the rules are the same for * as in the case of `const int * const a;`

As an additional note, your last line is not valid C89.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: It may be a preference to the programmer, but definitely not to the other guy who has to read his code!

Comment: The problem is not just in writing them, but also reading one someone else wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding these is to realise that the `*` binds to the `a`, not to the type.  So you should read these as:

```
const int a;    // a has type const int
int const a;    // a has type int const
const int * a;  // *a has type const int
int * const a;  // *(const a) has type int, which means *a has type int and a is const
int const * a const;    // *(const a) has type int const, which means *a has type const int and a is const.
```

(Note though that C++ references do not follow this rule).